# Flickity is not a function

Tags: jquery, flickity

I'm trying to have a custom button with a click functionality to move to the next slide. I am doing it exactly like in this official example: https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/emVpdz

But I get always this error from the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flickity is not a function
```

Here my code:

```
<script>
var $carousel = $('.main-carousel').flickity();

// previous
$('.button--previous').on( 'click', function() {
  $carousel.flickity('previous');
});

</script>
```

The flickity slider works perfectly but not this button/link outside.

Thanky you for any hints.
Best, L

Comment: works for me in Chrome.

Comment: Check the settings in the Codepen. They've included an additional script in the page: `https://npmcdn.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.js`. This is what you're missing.

Comment: check Rory's comment, and in addition check if you jQuery file is calling after the slider's JS, if not do it

Comment: Thank you for your answers! But I have already included flickity.pkgd.js and after this also jQuery. Still showing Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flickity is not a function. This is the site: https://archeoconcept.netzwerkstatt.cc/#

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure to include flickity.pkgd.js and jQuery library as the other comments mention, make sure to load both those before your custom code and not after your code. if you already have that then you need to use document ready callback and inside that initialize the code like this:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var $carousel = $('.main-carousel').flickity();

    // previous
    $('.button--previous').on( 'click', function() {
        $carousel.flickity('previous');
    });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me!
and was really simple you just need to first import the jquery script then the flickity.

Comment: You must post this answer as comment , not answer.

Comment: it says that you must have 50 reputation to comment